# Is there a vim.Folder for PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, if-statement, vim, type-conversion

Through my understanding, the vim.Folder *(type?)* is available for use in Python, but I need it for PowerShell. I am converting script, and there is an 'if' condition on whether a folder passed in the parameter is a vim.Folder .

```
    -----PowerShell Script-------

if($folder -isnot $someEquivalent){
    return Error
}

    -----Python Script-----------

if not isinstance(folder,vim.Folder):
    raise TypeError("Blah")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really post the full python script here you are trying to convert because noone knows what vim.folder is you are trying to compare to and while you are at it here is some basic powershell understanding for you.

In your script, you can check what type is an object by doing $folder | get-member or $folder.GetType();
Once you know what type of object it is then you compare like
if($folder-is [objecttype]) { ... }

I am assuming you want to compare $folder to vmware folder object type so try this:

```
if($folder -is [FolderImpl]) { ... }
or
if($folder -is [VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.Inventory.FolderImpl]) { ... }
```